# Как передать stream объект master-у в nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockjs

Я работаю с sockjs. Когда приходит stream объект (клиент) я отправляю его через worker в master процесс.

```
process.send({ client: connection })
```

`connection` - это стрим объект (клиент).

И когда я вызываю метод send выводится ошибка:

```
internal/child_process.js:609
var string = JSON.stringify(message) + '\n';
                      ^  
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`
```

С обычными объектами все нормально. Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: Речь идет о socket.io клиентах или о чем-то другом?

Comment: Да, точнее о sockjs.

Comment: Это не одно и то же. Если мне не изменяет память, в случае с socket.io вы вполне можете разделять клиентов между процессами используя redis для хранения общих данных. В то же время, оф. документация рекомендует работать с клиентом из того процесса, который установил с ним связь. Это нужно для правильной работы полифилов подключения.

Comment: А как сделать так чтобы они не терялись не знаете?

Comment: В рамках sockjs - не знаю. С другой стороны, это и не важно, до тех пор, пока у вас есть внешний балансировщик нагрузки и работа с подключением сосредоточена в воркере.

Comment: ngnix направил пользователя на сервер 1. но в сервере 1 нету клиентов. Они были на сервере 2. Я хотел бы узнать как не терять связь между клиентами в многопоточном режими или в многопроцессорном. Или я что то не правильно понял

Comment: Если честно, я не знаю возможно ли такое в рамках sockjs. Ждите экспертов по этой библиотеке.

Comment: А если на чистом websockets

Comment: Вряд ли. Тут дело не в библиотеке, отвечающей за соединение с клиентом, а в логике работы с подключениями на сервере. Как я уже говорил выше, можно попробовать socket.io. Он вроде должен нормально работать с несколькими потоками, используя redis для хранения подключений.

Comment: Да я бы использовал socket.io, просто там очень много мне не нужного, и ошибок там хватает

Answer (score 2):

В рамках вашего подхода исправить проблему не получится.

Фактически, все что вы можете передавать между процессами -- это строки. Отсюда и неявный вызов метода `JSON.stringify`, который превращает объект в строку.

Когда речь заходит о каких-то "живых" объектах, обладающих не только полями но и поведением (обработчиками событий, связями с другими объектами, и т.д.), то даже если вы сможете успешно сериализовать объект, вам все равно не удастся *правильно восстановить* его в другом процессе.

Даже если бы вам удалось передать объект полностью в другой процесс без сериализации, вы все равно бы потеряли при передаче все его связи, подключенные обработчики и т.д. Все этот просто осталось бы в рабочем процессе.

А что касается ошибки, то это всего лишь упоминание о циклических ссылках в сериализуемом объекте. Это всего лишь одно из следствий проблемы, обозначенной выше.

Answer (score 1):

Приветствую.

Судя по ошибке при конвертации `connection` в строку происходит зацикливание.

Пример такого объекта:

```
a = {}
b = {
  "a": a
}
a.b = b;

JSON.stringify(a); // выдаст ошибку
JSON.stringify(b); // тоже выдаст ошибку
```

Решение: передавать не весь `connection` целиком а только ту часть, с которой надо работать

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37613/discussion-on-answer-by-maxim-bogdanov---stream--master---nod).

Answer (score 0):

Узнал как решить проблему.
Когда запускаю дочерний процесс даю номер этому процессу.
Когда приходит сокет клиент, отправляю его ID и номер процесса главному процессу.